# With Highcharts 10.3.3, How do I move the box of the interactive toggles from inside the chart to the bottom of the chart?

Tags: highcharts

There is an interactive box which can toggle (show or hide) specific metrics in the chart.

It is currently blocking the chart and looks very ugly. How do I move it to the bottom of the chart?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `legend` options. Make sure that the properties are defined as below:

```
  legend: {
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    layout: 'vertical'
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ly8x15wt/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend